# react dynamically inject a property on a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

having a problem figuring this out. If I had a component such as

```
<Stack horizontal>..whatever...</Stack>
```

How could I make the **horizontal** attribute be inline kind of like

```
<Stack {this.horizontal ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical'>..whatever..</Stack>
```

In this scenario, it isn't adding a parameter such as className={this.class}, it is just the attribute itself.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems strange that you didn't assign this value to something

Comment: It is the fluent ui library, it is either <Stack horizontal> or  <Stack vertical> Just having the parameter indicates the orientation. Hmm.. maybe horizontal=horizontal would still work, I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an attribute just use props:

```
const myValue = this.horizontal ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical'
<Stack {myValue}>..whatever..</Stack>
```

If that doesn't work maybe you can even do:

```
if (this.horizontal) {
   comp = <Stack horizontal>..whatever..</Stack>
} else {
 comp = <Stack vertical>..whatever..</Stack>
}
```

And then maybe return

```
{comp}
```

in the render?

Comment: This isn't what I am trying to do unfortunately. I just want the keyword horizontal or vertical to be injected, the result needs to be <Stack horizontal> or <Stack vertical>

Comment: Yes, this works and is what I am doing currently. The problem is that the fluent ui seems to have a lot of attributes like this so I am looking for a solution to embedding the attribute. It has been frustrating to say the least.

Comment: One thing that can be done like, define all those attributes in an array then filter based on the values. By this you'll get the attributes which have data for then join the array elements using space. Something like this
`let attributes = ["attr1", "attr2"];
attributes = attributes.filter(attribute => !!attribute);
<Stack attributes.join(" ")>.whatever..</Stack>
`